# Particle engine problem

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, particles

i am implementing particle engine and here is my code:

```
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init] )) 
    {
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        emitter = [[CCParticleMeteor alloc] init];
        emitter.texture     =   [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"stars.png"];
        emitter.position    =   ccp( 240, 160 );
        [self addChild:emitter];

    }
    return self;
}
-(BOOL) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self ccTouchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch    =   [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location    =   [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    CGPoint point       =   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    emitter.position    =   ccp(point.x , point.y);
    return YES;
}
```

And Here is the Screen shot:
[image]

Here is i want to need:

1-I want to change the direction of effect( Means flame move upward but i want downward).

2-I want to change the color of flame.

Please help if you can.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) A quick look at the [particle system documentatio](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.2/interface_c_c_particle_system.html)n gives you either angle or gravity to play with - try setting these to different values i.e.

```
emitter.angle = <the angle you want>
```

2) Edit stars.png to be the colour you want?